# CompletableFuture.runAsync not executing the number of times it was invoked

Tags: java, executorservice, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

I am new to asynchronus coding in Java.

This is my code in spring boot application:

```
public void func(String someString){
       if(someString != null){
            doAsync(someString);
            publish(topic, someString);
       }
}

public void doAsync(String someString) {
        log.info("Inside do Async");
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                execute(someString);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                log.error("Error");
            }
        }, executorService);
    }

private void execute(String someString) {
        try {
            log.info("Inside Execute");
            DBcall(someString);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.info("Error");
        }
    }
```

The `func()` is being called around 200k times through an event in a Queue, In logs the log `Inside do Async` appeared for 200k times but the log `Inside Execute` appeared just for 195k times.

I see no errors/exception occurred in this flow.
Why is it not running consistently for all 200k events? Am I missing something in the implementation?

The `publish()` function publishes the same message to another subscriber which is in the same service, there are some 10k-11k errors in that subscriber flow(null pointer error). Is error in this flow is main reason behind not executing all async call?

Comment: Cannot think of other reason except all threads in the thread-pool are busy and the tasks that you cannot see are waiting to be executed. BTW, what's `executorService` (`FixedThreadPool`, `CachedThreadPool`)?

Comment: @adarsh But still after many hours I dont see the log for the task that might been delayed. Its ThreadPoolExecutor with max pool of 50.

Comment: You should provide a [mre] as it won’t be possible for us to reproduce your issue in its current form.

Comment: @DidierL not sure what all other details can help you here, I have updated the question, pls let me know.

Comment: Maybe some of the threads are blocked inside `execute`. Looking at a thread dumps might reveal some clues.

Comment: Well, as currently the code provided is not sufficient to reproduce the problem, one can only guess what it could be, it’s not possible to try and debug it. Hence the need for a [mre].